# BatteryManager stats not working on Android

Tags: android, batterymanager

I am trying to get the batter level using a BroadCastReceiver:

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 0);
```

I have added the following permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```

When I print the level and scale, I see the default value of 0. Are there additional settings to it?

Comment: Might be worth reading this [blog entry](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html) describing how to get at the battery stats....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Calculating Battery Level in %:](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#CurrentLevel)

You can find the current battery charge by extracting the current battery level and scale from the battery status intent as shown here:

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Implement BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
 BroadcastReceiver mybatteryReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                Log.d("TEMP","Battery Level in % is:: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
```

Get a Code from here It is tried and tested. Works fine.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y6q5wu526ngz7t/BatteryStats.zip

Result of the code :
[image]

Comment: I have the exact implementation but the level and scale are always coming up with the default value of -1.

Comment: are you testing on real device or emulator?

Comment: Look at my updated answer for the link to download the code which I tried and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No Permission Required for getting the battery charge status just use the following code in your broadcast receiver :-

int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

This will result in battery Level :)