# Get Battery Level

Tags: android, broadcast, batterylevel

I'm trying to get Battery state. I use this code :

```
public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences prefs;
int scale = -1;
int level = -1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    // temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
    // voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
    float nivel = level / (float) scale;
    Log.e("level",level+"");
    Log.e("scale",scale+"");
    Log.e("batteryLevel",nivel+"");
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

<receiver android:name="com.spg.receiver.BatteryLevelReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

With that code, that I got with those threads :

[Get battery level and state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

[BatteryManager stats not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682841/batterymanager-stats-not-working-on-android)

But each time, level and scale have value -1.

I don't know what am I missing...

Comment: There's a couple other posts about this... try putting '0' instead of '-1' as the second argument of your level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

Comment: Hmmm actually the 2nd argument is the default value, so it'll be interesting to see what it logs, 0 or -1 ... then at least you'll know whether intent is getting fired properly

Comment: I changed it to 0, and now, it get me 0 all the times, so it enters well in Broadcast

Answer (score 2):

[BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) provides constants for the [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) `Intent` not `BATTERY_LOW` or `BATTERY_OKAY`. In addition `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` must be registered programmatically, which you can do in `onCreate`. Since it can't be received by a `BroadcastReceiver` make sure you don't need to use a `Service` instead, such as you need to receive battery events at startup.

Comment: I don't understand well the last part of your answer, but I can't find that in official documentation. Can you please tell me more???

Comment: I don't know when you need to receive this `Intent` so I'm suggesting you may need to reconsider using `BroadcastReceiver` since you cannot rely on an `Android Manifest` based `IntentFilter` to start your `BroadcastReceiever`.

Comment: In the fifth activity, I need to take picture. If low battery, I need to know the battery state, if low, cancel the picture taking and follow the flow.